# Destroying server instance : ASIO C++

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Referring to [HTTP Server- Single threaded Implementation](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.2/doc/asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html)
I am trying to Explicitly control Lifetime of server instance

My Requirements are:

`1) I should be able to explicitly destroy the server`

`2) I need to keep multiple Server Instances alive which should listen to different ports`

`3) Manager Class maintains list of all active server instances; should be able to create and destroy the server instances by create and drop methods`

I am trying to implement **Requirement 1** and 
I have come up with code:

```
    void server::stop()
    {
        DEBUG_MSG("Stopped");
        io_service_.post(boost::bind(&server::handle_stop, this));
    }
```

where `handle_stop()` is

```
void server::handle_stop()
    {
        // The server is stopped by cancelling all outstanding asynchronous
        // operations. Once all operations have finished the io_service::run() call
        // will exit.
        acceptor_.close();
        connection_manager_.stop_all();
    }
```

I try to call it from `main()` as:

```
try
{
    http::server::server s("127.0.0.1","8973");
    // Run the server until stopped.
    s.run();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(3));
    s.stop();
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

**Question 1)**
I am not able to call `server::handle_stop()`.

I suppose `io_service_.run()` is blocking my `s.stop()` call.

```
void server::run()
{
    // The io_service::run() call will block until all asynchronous operations
    // have finished. While the server is running, there is always at least one
    // asynchronous operation outstanding: the asynchronous accept call waiting
    // for new incoming connections.
    io_service_.run();
}
```

How do I proceed?

**Question 2:**
For requirement 2) where I need to have `multiple server instances`, i think I will need to create an `io_service instance` in main and must pass the same instance to all `server instances`. Am I right?

Is it mandatory to have `only one io_service instance` per process or can I have more than one ?

**EDIT**

My aim is to implement a class which can control multi server instances:

Something of below sort (Incorrect code // Just giving view, what I try to implement ) I want to achieve-
How do i design?

I have confusion regarding `io_Service` and how do I cleanly call `mng.create()`, `mng.drop()`

```
  Class Manager{
    public:
    void createServer(ServerPtr)
    {
     list_.insert(make_shared<Server> (ip, port));
    }
    void drop()
    {
    list_.drop((ServerPtr));
    }
    private:
    io_service iO_;
    set<server> list_;
    };


    main()
    {
    io_service io;
    Manager mng(io);

    mng.createServer(ip1,port1);
    mng.createServer(ip2,port2);

    io.run();

    mng.drop(ip1,port1);
    }
```

Comment: ``io_service`` is thread safe, you don't need ``mutex`` until you handle lifetime of servers in one thread (if not you need to protect your ``set`` of servers for example with ``mutex``). There is no way you can do ``drop`` after ``run`` (of course until ``run`` had not exited), you need another thread for ``run`` or use ``poll``.

Comment: Even if  I run my `io.run()` in separate thread, I am not able to call `mng.drop()`.  I think `async_connect()` holds it back. How do I proceed?

Comment: Debug your program and find a place where it hangs. I recommend you to ask another more specific question after you identify the problem.

Comment: You can also use the `io_service::work`  approach, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594736/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-many-buffers-with-boostasio-method-async-send-to/28596450#28596450

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to call `server::handle_stop()`.

As you say, `run()` won't return until the service is stopped or runs out of work. There's no point calling `stop()` after that.

In a single-threaded program, you can call `stop()` from an I/O handler - for your example, you could use a `deadline_timer` to call it after three seconds. Or you could do something complicated with `poll()` rather than `run()`, but I wouldn't recommend that.

In a multi-threaded program, you could call it from another thread than the one calling `run()`, as long as you make sure it's thread-safe.

> For [multiple servers] I think I will need to create an `io_service` instance in main

Yes, that's probably the best thing to do.

> Is it mandatory to have only one `io_service` instance per process or can I have more than one?

You can have as many as you like. But I think you can only run one at a time on a single thread, so it would be tricky to have more than one in a single-threaded program. I'd have a single instance that all the servers can use.

Comment: Suppose I write a multi-threaded application using `server class` where each thread will run its separate `server instance`. Should I keep one copy of  `io_service` and keet it in `critical section`. What would be the best design.

Comment: @GauravK: If you want one thread per server, you probably want one `io_service` per server. You might be better off with one common `io_service`, one `strand` per server (or per connection), and one thread per CPU core, all running the `io_service` as a pool.

Comment: I asked it incorrectly. Suppose I have a `Communication Manager Class` which keeps track of all active server instances in a `set`. It also provides `create_server`  and  `drop_server` methods and has complete control over lifetimes of server instances. I want to make `io_service as member of this Manager class` and same would be passed to all threads. My main would initiiaze `communication manager` and `any access by any server instance i.e. threads`  will be protected by `mutex`. Is it a complicated design?

Comment: Some thing of this sort I want to implement `Class Manager{
public:
void createServer(ServerPtr)
{
 list_.insert(make_shared<Server> (ip, port));
}
void drop()
{
list_.drop((ServerPtr));
}
private:
io_service iO_;
set<server> list_;
};


main()
{
io_service io;
Manager mng(io);

mng.createServer(ip1,port1);
mng.createServer(ip2,port2);

io.run();

mng.drop(ip1,port1);
}`

Comment: @GauravK: I can't really review your design here (although the concept of a "manager" class smells of over-complication to me, and the talk of mutexes/critical sections instead of ASIO's concurrency support is rather scary). If you have a specific question, then ask it as a question.

Comment: I have added the EDIT section .. How do I achieve that wrt to `io_service`  behavior if u can help ...

Comment: @GauravK: Please ask one question per question. There were already two, and now you've added a third. If you're asking how to safely create and destroy servers from a different thread to the `io_service`, then don't. Post the operations to the `io_service`, so they can be done safely in the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are right, it's not working because you call `stop` after blocking `run`, and `run` blocks until there are some unhandled callbacks. There are multiple ways to solve this and it depands from what part of program `stop` will be called:

   - If you can call it from another thread, then run each instance of server in separate thread.
   - If you need to stop `server` after some IO operation for example you can simply do as you have tried `io_service_.post(boost::bind(&server::handle_stop, this));`, but it should be registered from another thread or from another callback in current thread.
   - You can use [`io_service::poll()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html). It is non-blocking version of `run`, so you create a loop where you call `poll` until you need to stop server.
2. You can do it both ways. Even with the link you provided you can take a look at:

   - [HTTP Server 3](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.2/doc/asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_3) - `An HTTP server using a single io_service and a thread pool`
   - and [HTTP Server 2](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.2/doc/asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_2) - `An HTTP server using an io_service-per-CPU design`